# Java Object input stream readObject();

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream

I have saved an object to an array list and saved the file as .dat, but when I want to read the object it is just showing null and not the values.

The Class

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
  public static String Name;
  public static String Contact;

  public Person(String Name, String Contact) {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Contact = Contact;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return Name;
  }

  public String getContact() {
    return Contact;
  }
}
```

The code

```
FileInputStream fis;
try {
  fis = new FileInputStream("Person.dat");
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
  ArrayList<Person> per = (ArrayList<Person>) ois.readObject();
  ois.close();

  per.get(0);
  Person pe = per.get(0);
  System.out.println(pe.getName());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined static members `Name` and `Contact` which are not serialized. Remove the `static` modifier to make this work.

Comment: Also, naming conventions should be followed (`name` and `contact`).

Answer (score 0):

Only `non-transient` and `non-static` fields will be serialized.

Refer to oracle documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html) and [jusfortechies](http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/serialization.php) article.

Change

```
public static String Name;
public static String Contact;
```

to

```
public String Name;
public String Contact;
```